# Send HTTP request with header containing 'é' in latin1 encoding

Tags: node.js, http, http-headers

I'm trying to automate a software (for task automation) but it seems it's vérifying headers (the user-agent specificly).

The wanted user agent contains a é but I can't seem to find a way to send that. It's beeing converted to UTF8.

(Note: I'm using the `request` module)